# Refrencing VB 6.0 Dll from VS.Net 2010 Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb6

Does anyone have tried refrencing vb 6.0 dll from VS.Net 2010 Project?

We have our business layer in VB 6.0 and I want to create a seperate project in VS.Net 2010, which is refrencing vb 6.0 dll (refrencing business layer)

If that is possible please let me know how can i achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have your VB6 business objects as COM object.

In VS.NET, use the Project | Add Reference menu option to bring up the Add Reference dialog. Click on the COM tab, which gives you a list of all the COM components registered currently on your system. Scroll down and select your dll from VB6.

Comment: The Browse tab will give him an easier time to find it.

Comment: Nope it was not as easy as it sounds.  I am getting assembly or com component is not valid while trying to reference vb 6.0 dll.  Note this is not control, it is actual business layer contains classes and objects.

Comment: When you can't register a VB6 dll it may well be because that dll relies on some other file.  If you have setup, from your VB6 app.  Use that setup it will install all required files.  If you don't than you have to manually install all dependent components.

Answer (score 0):

If the .dll is not registered, use the Project | Add Reference menu option to bring up the Add Reference dialog. Click on the Browse tab, find/select your dll on the filesystem and click OK.